# Paypal IPN works from sandbox but not from IPN simulator

Tags: paypal

When I test IPN from my sandbox it works- but when I test it from the IPN simulator

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/

I get this message:IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.

I use the exact same IPN url in my sandbox as I use in the simulator. Does anyone have any ideas of what is causing this?

Comment: Just to give everyone an update- I tried using the IPN simulator again- this time it worked-but I am still curious if anyone else has had a similar experience with the IPN simulator.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I struggled with getting the sandbox to work for some reason. I got the IPN simulator up and running, ditched the rest of the sandbox, and then tested it live with $1 payments. 
For the IPN sim, all of the php code in the verified column has to work perfectly or it rejects the handshake. I hope this give you peace of mind.